TeX/Context format of sections and subsections
In the documentation of context I like how sections and subsections display.

Notice :

the text (section head) has some color
there are an underline with some color and thickness
the section and subsections are (negatively) indented with respect to body text

Unfortunately, the documentation is not precise on how to achieve it.
I tried the following code (and several variations, see commented parts) but wasn't able to get the desired result.

The value of OverlayWidth send to the metapost code seem to be zero. I would be grateful if someone can propose a convenient approach.

This looks like the MetaFun manual. You can look at the source. The files are available in
./tex/texmf-context/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/metafun/

In particular, grepping for setuphead in that directory, you will be lead to metafun-environment.tex. I leave it to you as an exercise to find the setup of the chapter (it uses a command).

A question regarding the same chapter style was asked about two weeks ago on the ConTeXt mailing list with the required code from the manual th get it.

Following the suggestion of mickep, I was able to get desired output with the following code:
% Define a custom section style using MetaPost for the underline
 \startuniqueMPgraphic{SectionUnderline}
   path p; 
   p:= unitsquare xscaled OverlayWidth yscaled OverlayHeight;
   pickup pencircle scaled 1mm;
   drawoptions(withcolor .625yellow);
   draw llcorner p -- lrcorner p;
   setbounds currentpicture to p;
 \stopuniqueMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[SectionUnderline][\uniqueMPgraphic{SectionUnderline}]

\starttexdefinition unexpanded MySection #1#2
  \hskip-.75cm\relax
  \framed [
    background=SectionUnderline,
    frame=off,
    offset=0pt
  ] {
    #1\color[darkred]{.} #2
  }
\stoptexdefinition

% Apply the custom section style to sections
\setuphead
  [section]
    [ 
    color=darkred,
    style=\bfa,
    command=\MySection
    ]

\starttext

 \section{Introduction}
 This is the introduction.

 \section{A second section}
 This is another section. 

\stoptext

